# Modeling an hrf time series in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, convolution

I'm attempting to model fMRI data so I can check the efficacy of an experimental design. I have been following a couple of tutorials and have a question.
I first need to model the BOLD response by convolving a stimulus input time series with a canonical haemodynamic response function (HRF). The first tutorial I checked said that one can make an HRF that is of any amplitude as long as the 'shape' of the HRF is correct so they created the following HRF in matlab:

```
hrf = [ 0 0 1 5 8 9.2 9 7 4 2 0 -1 -1 -0.8 -0.7 -0.5 -0.3 -0.1 0 ]
```

And then convolved the HRF with the stimulus by just using 'conv' so:

```
hrf_convolved_with_stim_time_series = conv(input,hrf);
```

This is very straight forward but I want my model to eventually be as accurate as possible so I checked a more advanced tutorial and they did the following. First they created a vector of 20 timepoints then used the 'gampdf' function to create the HRF.

```
t = 1:1:20; % MEASUREMENTS
h = gampdf(t,6) + -.5*gampdf(t,10); % HRF MODEL
h = h/max(h); % SCALE HRF TO HAVE MAX AMPLITUDE OF 1
```

Is there a benefit to doing it this way over the simpler one? I suppose I have 3 specific questions.

1. The 'gampdf' help page is super short and only says the '6' and '10' in each function call represents 'A' which is a 'shape' parameter. What does this mean? It gives no other information. Why is it 6 in the first call and 10 in the second?
2. This question is directly related to the above one. This code is written for a situation where there is a TR = 1 and the stimulus is very short (like 1s). In my situation my TR = 2 and my stimulus is quite long (12s). I tried to adapt the above code to make a working HRF for my situation by doing the following:

   ```
   t = 1:2:40; % 2s timestep with the 40 to try to equate total time to above
   h = gampdf(t,6) + -.5*gampdf(t,10); % HRF MODEL
   h = h/max(h); % SCALE HRF TO HAVE MAX AMPLITUDE OF 1
   ```

Because I have no idea what the 'gampdf' parameters mean (or what that line does, in all actuality) I'm not sure this gives me what I'm looking for. I essentially get out 20 values where 1-14 have SOME numeric value in them but 15-20 are all 0. I'm assuming there will be a response during the entire 12s stimulus period (first 6 TRs so values 1-6) with the appropriate rectification which could be the rest of the values but I'm not sure.

Final question. The other code does not 'scale' the HRF to have an amplitude of 1. Will that matter, ultimately?

Answer (score 0):

The canonical HRF you choose is dependent upon where in the brain the BOLD signal is coming from. It would be inappropriate to choose just any HRF. Your best source of a model is going to come from a lit review. I've linked a paper discussing the [merits of multiple HRF models](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3318970/). The methods section brings up some salient points.